# EXCEL VBA procedure ambigous name

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code is too large and I'm trying to make smaller SUBS so the error won't come up, but then the error "Ambigoius name" pops up. I've tried to rename my subs... 
Ex.

```
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
Range("I9").Interior.Color=Range("AK9").Display.Format.Interior.Color
end sub
Private Sub worksheet_calculate2()
Range("J9").Interior.Color=Range("AQ9").Display.Format.Interior.Color
end sub
```

...when I rename the other subs as shown in the example it doesn't do anything, only the original work properly. How do I rename them so they can work properly?

Comment: Could you post the other code you mentioned in your post? Also, I think you should paste the returned error instead of mentioning it.

Comment: I am assuming that you want these subs to run automatically when the underlying worksheet is calculated. Yet, only one (the first one) gets executed. Is that right? If so, you should write into the first sub called `Private Sub worksheet_calculate()` something like `Call worksheet_calculate2` and then the second sub will also run.

Comment: "Ambiguous name" usually means you have two SUBs with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert the below line of codes at the end of your main sub which is "worksheet_calculate"

```
Call worksheet_calculate2
Call worksheet_calculate3
Call worksheet_calculate4
Call worksheet_calculate4
.
.
.
Call worksheet_calculaten
```

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding,  `worksheet_calculate` is the predefined name of the subroutine, triggered by the event when the worksheet is recalculated.

You can define and call other private subs from it.
like

```
Private Sub worksheet_calculate()
   rem sub body
   CalculateSub1 pars        'variant one
   Call CalculateSub1(pars)  'variant two
   rem sub body
End Sub

Sub CalculateSub1(pars)
   Rem Sub body
End Sub
```